# How to give Tesseract a word list (.NET wrapper)

Tags: .net, tesseract

TLDR; version:

Does anyone have a working 'bazaar' config for Tasseract using the .NET wrapper that I could see?

I'm pretty sure that's what I want (only recognise some words from a list), but it doesn't seem to do anything

---

I have a pretty short list of possible strings I'm trying to find (1-4 words). The documentation for Tesseract states:

> If you want to replace the whole dictionary, you will need to unpack
> the .traineddata file, create a new word-dawg file, and then pack the
> files back into a .traineddata file. See TrainingTesseract for more
> details.

That sounds like what I want! So I look at [TrainingTesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract) and see:

> The traineddata file is simply a concatenation of the input files,
> with a table of contents that contains the offsets of the known file
> types. See ccutil/tessdatamanager.h in the source code for a list of
> the currently accepted filenames.

Great. So how do I go about unpacking this simple concatenation of input files, modifying the content and header and re-packing it, then? :)

[This post](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#config-files-and-augmenting-with-user-data) appears to be the same question - which involves simply turning off the default dictionary and using user-words instead:

> let’s suppose you want to OCR in English, but suppress the normal
> dictionary and load an alternative word list and an alternative list
> of patterns — these two files are the most commonly used extra data
> files.
>
> If your language pack is in /path/to/eng.traineddata and the hocr
> config is in /path/to/configs/hocr then create three new files:
>
> /path/to/eng.user-words: -snip
>
> /path/to/eng.user-patterns: -snip
>
> /path/to/configs/bazaar: -snip
>
> Now, if you pass the
> word bazaar as a trailing command line parameter to Tesseract,
> Tesseract will not bother loading the system dictionary nor the
> dictionary of frequent words and will load and use the eng.user-words
> and eng.user-patterns files you provided. The former is a simple word
> list, one per line. The format of the latter is documented in
> dict/trie.h on read_pattern_list().

But having done this it's made no difference at all!

I'm creating the engine with:

```
using (engine = new TesseractEngine(@"C:\src\x\tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default, @"C:\src\x\tessdata\engine.config"))
```

Having made a (UTF-8, unix line endings) file engine.config:

```
load_system_dawg     F
load_freq_dawg       F
user_words_suffix    user-words
user_patterns_suffix user-patterns
```

And created eng.user-patterns and eng.user-words (UTF-8, Unix line ending) files alongide the eng.traineddata.

Comment: I wonder if this is possible? I wonder if anyone is using Tesseract other than the developers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out?

Looks like here is a way to increase its' preference of finding dictionary words:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#how-to-increase-the-trust-instrength-of-the-dictionary

**How to increase the trust in/strength of the dictionary?**

For tesseract-ocr < 3.01 try upping NON_WERD and GARBAGE_STRING in dict/permute.cpp to maybe 3 or even 5.

For tesseract-ocr >= 3.01 try increasing the variables language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word and language_model_penalty_non_dict_word in a config file. By default they are 0.1 and 0.15 respectively.

Comment: Nope. never figured it out. Nothing I did seemed to the config make any difference (except when it got a lot worse a couple times)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking but here's what I use.

```
TesseractEngine _ocrEngine = new TesseractEngine("tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default);
_ocrEngine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1579ABCDE "); // this is how you specify a variable
_ocrEngine.TryPrintVariablesToFile("allv.txt"); // this could help you see all possible variables
```

`user_words_file` is also a variable you can use - I assume you can set the path there as well, but I didn't test it.